# How to change a KEY in yaml data

Tags: python, string, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml

I have below yaml file as a template. From another python program I am fetching the name of the device, assume `deviceB` is the name of the new device. Can someone show how to replace the `deviceA` with `deviceB` using python (replace the mapping KEY but not the VALUE)?

The place holder for the device is fixed & does not vary.

#### Yaml Data:

```
testbed:
    name: "boot-ios"
devices:
    deviceA:
        type: IOS
        connections:
            defaults:
                 class: 
            a:
              protocol: telnet
              ip: 
              port:
```

Comment: Is it important that the order of the devices (assuming there are multiple in the real file) stays the same? Do you want to preserve any comments in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the data in, and then duplicate the key like:

#### Code:

```
import yaml

with open('file1', 'rU') as f:
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)

data['devices']['deviceB'] = data['devices']['deviceA']
del data['devices']['deviceA']

with open('file1', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(data, f)
```

#### Results:

```
devices:
  deviceB:
    connections:
      a: {ip: null, port: null, protocol: telnet}
      defaults: {class: null}
    type: IOS
testbed: {name: boot-ios}
```

Comment: You should always use [`yaml.safe_load()`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#loading-yaml)